# Electron setLoginItemSettings doesn't work on tray menu app

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, electron-builder

I am trying to auto launch my electron app, electron docs provide the [instructions](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetloginitemsettingssettings-macos-windows).
I tried electron-quick-start app with this code:

```
app.setLoginItemSettings({
  openAtLogin: true
})
```

This works fine without any issue.

But my electron app is just a main process running in background (no BrowserWindow). And when I use this setting in it creates startup entry but doesn't start on windows login.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of trial I found out that, electron app with administrative privilege can't auto launch on startup. You need to remove that privilege from package.json and then it should work normally.

Comment: Could you pleaase provide exaple how to remove it and where exactly